# Como fazer a soma de um registro do banco mais input com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Ola como faço para fazer essa soma com Jquery:

tenho essa tabela **veiculos** no banco de dados com a coluna revisao de 500

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no formulario quando eu escolher o prefixo MT-02 quero que ele faça a soma do input horimetro da troca(que vai ser digitado)  + revisao (que esse registro esta no banco de dados) e dar o resultado no input horimetro da proxima troca

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tenho essa soma mais nao esta pegando o registro do banco de dados (para referencia) **veja onde tem 500 no codigo nao queria colocar o numero e sim pegar o registro que esta no banco de dados**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('input').on('keyup',function(){
        if(jQuery(this).attr('name') === 'result'){
            return false;
        }

        var horimetroca = (jQuery('#horimetroca').val() == '' ? 0 : jQuery('#horimetroca').val());
        var proximatroca = (parseInt(horimetroca) + 500);
        jQuery('#proximatroca').val(proximatroca);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Cara não sei se vou te ajudar, mas eu faria um evento 'change' no campo veículo, que quando alterasse fizesse uma requisição ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) passando o valor do campo (ex.: MT-02) e no back end faria um select usando o MT-02 no where, e então retornaria pro front, somaria e exibiria no campo.

Comment: Bem-vindo Diogo Carvalho, para obter respostas nas suas próximas perguntas não deixe de ler esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e esse também https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/

Comment: Caso alguma resposta resolva seu problema não deixe de marcá-la como aceita. Veja como `marcar` nessa imagem https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e saber o porque nesse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Um exemplo simples mas dá para você entender como funciona:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
<!--
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //executa função no clique do botão class addMore
        $(".addMore").click(function(){
                //recupera os valores do formulário
                var prefixo = $("#prefixo").val();
                var horimetro = $("#horimetro").val();

                //prepara para enviar com o ajax para a buscaVeiculo.php
                var dataString = {"valorPrefixo":prefixo,"valorHorimetro":horimetro }

              $.ajax({
                url: 'buscaVeiculo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data){
                //insere no input de id horimetroProxima o valor retornado    
                $("#horimetroProxima").val(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                //caso haja erro a frase abaixo será apresentada na div de id resultado    
                $("#resultado").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
                }
             });//ajax 

        });
    });
//-->
</script>

<div id="resultado"></div>

<select id="prefixo" size="1">
    <option>Veiculo</option>
    <option value="MT-02">MT-02</option>
    <option value="DF-02">DF-02</option>
    <option value="CM-01">CM-01</option>
</select>

<input id="horimetro" type="text"> <input id="horimetroProxima" type="text" readonly> <button class="addMore">add</button>
```

buscaVeiculo.php

```
$Prefixo = $_POST['valorPrefixo'];
$Horimetro = $_POST['valorHorimetro'];

$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_DB',"USUARIO","SENHA");

    $sql = $conexao->prepare("SELECT revisao FROM veiculos where prefixo='$Prefixo'");
    $sql->execute();

    $linha = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $Revisao = $linha['revisao'];

    echo $Revisao+ $Horimetro;
```

### Talvez você possa gostar dessa solução

Script

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //$("#horimetro").blur(function(){
        $( ".qqum" ).on( "blur keyup change", function() {

            var prefixo = $("#prefixo").val();

            if (prefixo!="Veiculo"){

                var horimetro = $("#horimetro").val();
                var dataString = {"valorPrefixo":prefixo,"valorHorimetro":horimetro }

              $.ajax({
                url: 'buscaVeiculo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#horimetroProxima").val(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
                }
             });//ajax 
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<select class="qqum" id="prefixo" size="1">
    <option>Veiculo</option>
    <option value="MT-02">MT-02</option>
    <option value="DF-02">DF-02</option>
    <option value="CM-01">CM-01</option>
</select>

<input class="qqum" id="horimetro" type="text" placeholder="horimetro"> <input id="horimetroProxima" type="text" readonly>
```

Conforme mostrado no [**Online Notpad**](https://anotepad.com/notes/emh62c) do comentário do AP

há que se fazer varias alterações devido a `classes e ids` diferentes:

```
$( "#idVeiculo,#horimetroca" ).on( "blur keyup change", function() {                    
var prefixo = $("#idVeiculo").val();
if (prefixo!="Selecione"){
var horimetro = $("#horimetroca").val();
.............
.............
success: function(data){
   $("#proximatroca").val(data);
```

**Código na integra**

```
<?php

$conexao = new PDO ....

$resultipo = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM veiculos");
$resultipo->execute();
$resultados = $resultipo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Veiculo</label></b>
              <select name="idVeiculo" class="form-control select2" id="idVeiculo" style="width:100%;" >
              <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
      <?php
        foreach($resultados as $results):
      ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $results['prefixo'] ?>"><?php echo $results['prefixo']; ?></option>
      <?php
        endforeach;
      ?>
               </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Data da Troca</label></b>
               <input type="date" name="datatroca"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" class="form-control"  id="datatroca" />
          </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Km da Troca</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="kmtroca" id="kmtroca" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Soma da Proxima Troca em Ajax-->

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <script language="javascript">
                <!--
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        $( "#idVeiculo,#horimetroca" ).on( "blur keyup change", function() {

                            var prefixo = $("#idVeiculo").val();

                            if (prefixo!="Selecione"){

                                var horimetro = $("#horimetroca").val();
                                var dataString = {"valorPrefixo":prefixo,"valorHorimetro":horimetro }

                              $.ajax({
                                url: 'buscaVeiculo.php',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: dataString,
                                success: function(data){
                                    $("#proximatroca").val(data);
                                },
                                error: function(){
                                    $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
                                }
                             });//ajax 
                            }
                        });

                    });
                //-->
                </script>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Horimetro da Troca</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="horimetroca" id="horimetroca" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Horimetro da Proxima Troca</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" readonly="" name="proximatroca" id="proximatroca" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div id="resultados"></div>
```

Comment: nesse que voce mandou nao tem como ficar, tipo eu coloco o horimetro e assim que apertar o TAB ou selecionar outro input, ele ja inseria só sem ter que colocar esse botao de add.

Comment: Obrigado pelo o tempo dedicado nessa duvida, desculpa a demora para aceitar a resposta, funcionou certinho parabens...

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho, blz, editei a resposta colocando mais opções `blur keyup change` e sem o botão `add`

Comment: o buscaVeiculo.php vai ficar do mesmo jeito sem alteração?

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho, exato, o `buscaVeiculo.php` é o mesmo, sem alteração!!

Comment: Veja comeu codigo do formulario

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho, não entendi

Comment: for="inputDefault">Veiculo</label></b>
                  <select name="idVeiculo" class="form-control select2" id="idVeiculo" style="width:100%;" >
                  <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
          <?php
          $resultipo = "SELECT * FROM veiculos";
          $resultadotipo = mysqli_query($conn, $resultipo);
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadotipo)) {          
          ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row['idVeiculo']; ?>"><?php echo $row['prefixo']; ?></option>
                    <?php
          }
          ?>

Comment: veja meu formulario @leo-caracciolo

[link] (https://anotepad.com/notes/emh62c)

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho, vi, mas o que está ocorrendo?

Comment: entao nao esta funcionando, a duvida é, sera que é por causa do select que esta pegando o idVeiculo?

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho, vou colocar provisoriamente na resposta como deve funcionar. Se der certo me avise que retiro da resposta pq não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: tudo bem, ok...

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho, observe as classes e os ids para que estejam corretos

Comment: ok, obrigado deu tudo certinho.... valeu pela atenção e ajuda. realmente eras as classes e o ids so tive que fazer uma alteração no buscaVeiculo.php troquei so depois do where
    $sql = $conexao->prepare("SELECT revisao FROM veiculos where idVeiculo='$Prefixo'");

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho, blz, se puder coloca lá o certo no `anotepad.com` pra eu ver as modificações

Comment: pronto ja está lá, veja como ficou as modificações no form

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho, muito bom, mas eu fiz um pouco diferente, veja na resposta que editei.

Comment: maravilha ficou showww !!! parabens pela a dedicação...